# Can I search getJSON for certain value and then execute the right PHP?

Tags: php, onclick, event-handling, gson

As part of my web app I created a button that on click event should send push message to user mobile device (android or ios)

I am standing against two challenges:

First: Checking the value in order to decide if I need to pass it to the android or ios PHP script.
I don't know how to code it in JS but on PHP it should be something like this:

```
<?php
$token= 'APA34324324343';
$findme   = 'APA';
$pos = strpos($token, $findme);

if ($pos === false) {
    exec("ios_push.php $token > /dev/null &");
} else {
    exec("andorid_push.php $token > /dev/null &");
    }
?>
```

Second: Writing the correct syntax in the $.getJSON function that will take the $value and pass it on to the correct PHP script.
This is what I have right now:

```
    '<button onclick="' . 
    "var activeValue = $(this).siblings('.user_token_value');" . 
    "var activeCaption = $(this).siblings('.user_token_caption');"  .
    "$.getJSON(
    'send_push.php?id=" . $rowData['token'] .
```

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Abraham